# PAM conf files are insecure!

Tags: security, authentication, pam

PAM configuration files located in /etc/pam.d/ are vulnerable to physical attack. That is they can be modified from an external system (bootable USB or take drive to another machine)

Other than encrypting the whole drive is there another way to protect these PAM config files?

Comment: Don't let people have physical access to your machine.

Comment: That's not helpful.

Comment: It is the only solution that satisfies your criteria, so it’s maximally helpful.

Comment: Encrypting the drive and therefor the config files satisfies the issue of keeping people from modifying them and gaining quick access. Keeping people physically removed from the machine has no bearing on the question or the concern. Physical access is presumed within the question.

Comment: Great! You're allowed to [answer your own questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), so feel free to post one with your other solution(s) below.

Comment: Unfortunately encrypting the drive doesn't satisfy the "other than encrypting the drive" requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and for pointing out that I can answer my own question. The answer in this case is "No" to my original question. I'd say so, but I'm too new to answer. And, you're right,  encrypting the drive does not meet the requirements to my question. Your original comment seems to be the only one on point. The only way to keep the files from being tampered with is to keep people away from the system. Thank you. Sorry for the full circle here.

Comment: [The 10 Immutable Laws of Computer Security](http://www.cryptednets.org/2007/05). See also [What can a hacker do when he has physical access to a system?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19334)

Answer (score 6):

Physical access *is* root access. If you're able to change any part of the boot process, you're able to compromise the system.

It always depends on your **attack scenario**. If you believe that an attacker can change the PAM configuration, a full-disk encryption (FDE) can protect you against that. If you believe that the attacker replaces your FDE password prompt by some other tool to siphon your password, well, a locked down trusted boot chain is fine (see LinuxBoot, HEADS), but you're probably dealing with TPM at that point. HEADS makes this *really* secure, but its not completely production ready as far as I know.

However, those are all software mitigations. A *hardware key logger* placed between your keyboard and mainboard can again just send your input to an adversary. If they know at least *some* of your system (e.g. distribution or WM), they can also just replay a keyboard macro to send the data whenever there as has been an input pause for some time. Or they just copy your complete hard drive beforehand and use the recorded input to decrypt your their copy. Unless TPM or another enclave is used, it's almost impossible to prevent this kind of attack.

Therefore, let me repeat the first statement again: **physical access is root access**. If you want to slow a wannabe attacker down, then at least secure GRUB and your boot settings (e.g. any UEFI and/or boot order changes need a password), always boot from a specific hard drive, and use FDE. But keep in mind that all those actions make troubleshooting and support harder, just like reinforced doors and extra secure locks make it harder for a locksmith if you ever lose your keys.

But remember, it depends on **your** attack scenario. If I just want to deal some damage, I drop a bucket of water on your notebook.

---

To get back to your question: any means to protect the configuration files would be stored again somewhere. When someone modifies the files, they can just go ahead and change that meta file too. It's files all the way down.

Comment: I've encrypted the files. Thank you for your time and thoughts. As to physical access = root access, is there some bit of history form which that statement comes? On the surface it doesn't seem to be true. If the drive's are encrypted physical access does not equal access to the files and without full access then that does not equal root.

Comment: Don't take "root" as literal \*nix user in this case, but instead as "way to get complete access to the system or **data**, either now or **later**". ["It is a common saying in security"](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19334/), as compromised systems can do anything. Remember the key logger scenario: one installs the key logger, lets you use the PC for a while, and the comes back to use the logged keystrokes to login into your PC. Sure, the first physical access didn't breach any data, but the second one gained all of it, including complete control.

Comment: I should probably mention that *every* operating system is prone to those attacks. A USB key/message logger doesn't care about your operating system. A well-placed camera that can record your hands on the keyboard doesn't neither, and the latter doesn't even need any change to your PC. A fingerprint scanner can sometimes even be cheated by a fingerprint that was saved with tape. Multi factor authentication can make this harder, but that's not supported by all systems. Therefore, ask yourself: *who are your attackers?* FDE is probably more than enough.